# Referencing the instance of a generic type T

Tags: android, oop, kotlin, generic-programming

Is it possible to return the instance of Generic type T when Animal class override Zoo class?

`classInstance<T>() returns a type mismatch; required class<T> found T.`

```
    private inline fun <reified Eat : T> classInstance(): Eat = Eat::class.java.newInstance()


    abstract class Animal<Result> {

        abstract fun bark(): Class<Result>

    }

    open class Zoo<T>(protected var listener: RequestListener<T>?) : Callback<T>, Animal<T>() {

        override fun bark(): Class<T> = classInstance<T>()
    }
```

`bark()` function will be use for the following purpose:

`Gson().fromJson(inputStreamReaderResult, bark())` where, `bark()` must be of type Class

Comment: Do you mean `fun bark(): T`?

Comment: it should. be in the form  override fun bark(): Class<Rotwheiler> = Rotwheiler::class.java

Comment: Ok, then I'm not really understanding the problem. I thought you wanted to return an instance like you do in `classInstance`, but it seems that you actually want to return the class of `T`. Is this correct?

Comment: You are right, i must return class of T

Comment: oh I see. I don't have enough knowledge to help you out. To the best of my knowledge, inside classes, you can't really have reified types which makes it tricky to return the class of `T`. Usually, we leave the method such as `bark` to be implemented by the final class at which point they know how to implement `bark`. I don't know of a generic way to do it.

Comment: I let the final class return the class type of bark in a project. But i wanted to eliminate that dependency as it is being assign in many places.  Thank you Fred for your input.

Comment: Glad I could help. In any case, if all fails, you can always try the hacky `fun classOfT(): Class<T> = (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<T>`. This gives you the class of `T`, but I don't think it's the cleanest solution. It's the only way I know though.

Comment: Consider getting the `Class` object in the constructor of `Zoo`, and then potentially providing an `inline fun <reified T>` factory method for it.